# Ethernet connection - device does not exist

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, network-adapter

My Windows 10 desktop PC has an ethernet connection straight to the router. Often when I first start my PC, the ethernet connection does not work. My wireless devices still have internet during these times, and restarting my PC usually resolves the issue. I'm not sure how to diagnose what exactly is the problem. Here are some things I tried:

- Running network diagnostics. This fails with the error message: "The Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection adapter is experiencing driver- or hardware-related problems"
- In device manager, the Device Status of the network adapter is "This device cannot start. (Code 10) This device does not exist."
- Disabling and enabling the device in device manager results in the status "This device cannot start. (Code 10) {Operation Failed} The requested operation was unsuccessful."
- Attempting to update my driver from device manager (when I do have internet) gives "The best drivers for your device are already installed"
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the device from the device manager (following a comment by @Biswa, thanks!) resolves the issue for the current session. However, the next time the PC starts up the connection is down again.

**EDIT:** Simply clicking "Scan for hardware changes" in the Device Manager fixes the issue for the current session, but it reappears when the computer is restarted.

Comment: Do the lights around the Ethernet port blink? Is there any exclamation mark in device manager? Try to uninstall the device in device manager and reinstall the driver manually with installer.

Comment: I literally have the exact same experience right now. I thought I had posted this when I read it. My lights on the port do blink the entire time @Biswa

Comment: Have you tried updating the Ethernet driver?

Comment: @davidgo Yes. It tells me the best drivers are already installed.

Comment: @Biswa I haven't checked the lights. There is a yellow triangle in device manager. I'll try the uninstalling/reinstalling next time.

Comment: @Biswa uninstalling and reinstalling the driver fixes the problem for the current session (faster than restarting - thanks!), but the problem still occurs on subsequent start-ups.